# ASP.NET conditional formatting based on value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, colors, getelementbyid

I am new to both CSS and JavaScript, and I want to change the font color of this section of my .aspx file:

```
#.aspx
<script src="~/CSS/traffic_lights.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- This handles red/amber/green-->
<div class="Pr">
    <h3>Say what you will about this number:</h3>
    <asp:Label ID="lblResults2" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

My attempt involves adding a .js script to my project where I handle three cases:

```
#traffic_lights.js

//Red
if (document.getElementById("lblResults2").innerHTML >= 0 &&
    document.getElementById("lblResults2").innerHTML <= 30) {
    document.getElementById("lblResults2").style.color = "red";
}

//Amber (or orange)
if (document.getElementById("lblResults2").innerHTML > 30 &&
    document.getElementById("lblResults2").innerHTML <= 60) {
    document.getElementById("lblResults2").style.color = "orange";
}

//Green
if (document.getElementById("lblResults2").innerHTML > 60 &&
    document.getElementById("lblResults2").innerHTML < 101) {
    document.getElementById("lblResults2").style.color = "green";
}
```

There is no CSS file specifying which font color should be rendered, so I am not sure why this is not working. The text is always rendered in black, regardless of the numerical value in "Pr".

Comment: Your `<asp:Label>` has no Text. Also, are you using a master page? If so the ID might not actually be "lblResults2", you would have to add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your label. Also, is your javascript running after the page has fully loaded? `console.log` your `document.getElementById("lblResults2")` and see if its undefined or it actually gets found

Comment: It has an associated text field in the code-behind .cs file: `lblResults2.Text = pr_text`

Comment: Also in your javascript `.innerHTML` would be a string not an int, but you are comparing it like its an int (`>= 0`). You have to get the string value then `parseInt` to set it as an int for comparision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var val = parseInt($("#lblResults2").text());
        if (val >= 0 && val <= 30) {
            $("#lblResults2").css("color", "red");
        }
        else if (val > 30 && val <= 60) { $("#lblResults2").css("color", "orange"); }
        else if (val > 60 && val <= 100) { $("#lblResults2").css("color", "green"); }

    });

</script>



 <div class="Pr">
<h3>Say what you will about this number:</h3>
<asp:Label ID="lblResults2" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="99" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

you can change 'Text' attribute of asp:label